# custom labels and counters in r-markdown

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible to create an intext custom counter in r-markdown. For instance, say I have the following text

Einstein was a clever man **[Fact 1]**. Einstein worked for Princeton University **[Fact 2]**. Anyone who is employed by Princeton University is clever.

My ideal outcome is to define a counter for facts, with a specific formatting (e.g. bold and red in a bracket). So any time I call the counter it would print the counter label with the new number. Something like

Einstein was a clever man `factCounter`. Einstein worked for Princeton University `factCounter`. Anyone who is employed by Princeton University is clever.

Comment: You can do something like `[^1]` and it will create footnotes at the bottom. It sounds like you're describing a citation system which you can implement using bibtex or the footnotes method I mentioned. Not really sure to make it red though.

Comment: not my ideal solution. If possible, prefer a separate environment, so it wont mix up with the footnotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pandoc Lua filter would do the job:

```lua
local utils = require 'pandoc.utils'
local fact_counter = 0

function Code (code)
  if utils.stringify(code) == 'factCounter' then
    fact_counter = fact_counter + 1
    return pandoc.Str(string.format('[Fact %s]', fact_counter))
  end
end
```

Just add `--lua-filters=FILE-CONTAINING-ABOVE-CODE.lua` to your `pandoc_args` knitr options. All occurences of `` `factCounter` `` in your text will be replaced by an actual fact count.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am unfamiliar with editing the pandoc Lua filter. Would all of the above go to the yaml, on top of the rmd file? If not, would you please provide some directions on the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This can be natively done in `r`. Its an hack though.
Initialize the counter in the first `r` chunk as shown below.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,warning = FALSE)
X = 1
```
````

Then use the following in line r command to increment and print at the same time. This could be done using any programming language supported by rmarkdown  or the "new" quarto.

### My Section

Problem no. `r ({X=X+1})`.

Add 2+2

Solution `r X`.

2 +2 = 4

Problem `r ({X=X+1})`